# ffmpeg AAC audio encoding with libfdk_aac: difference between -q:a and -vbr quality parameters?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac, bitrate, m4a

I want to encode an audio file to AAC, using libfdk_aac, and I'm wondering about the quality parameters. I want to use variable bitrate encoding, not constant bitrate.

It seems I can specify the quality either with the `-vbr N` parameter (with `N`=1..5) like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -acodec libfdk_aac -vbr 4 output.m4a
```

Or using the `-q:a N` parameter (here `N`=0..9) like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -acodec libfdk_aac -q:a 7 output.m4a
```

How are these two related, is there a substantial difference? Do specific `-q:a` values correspond to certain `-vbr` values, or is it a different encoding approach altogether?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, after some experimenting I found out that the `-q:a` parameter does not apply to the libfdk_aac encoder, only to ffmpeg's native AAC encoder (which is inferior).

Hence always use `-vbr` with libfdk_aac. Leaving this here for reference in case anyone else may ever be wondering about this.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know, are you using vbr for streaming? any downside?